# How to specify the middle points when plan projectory using moveit?

Tags: ros, points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can specify start and goal to plan a projectory. but I want specify some middle points between start and goal.

I only know that the computeCartesianPath can do that. but It isn't good for use.

How to specify the middle points when plan projectory using moveit?

advance thank for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251246/how-to-specify-the-middle-points-when-plan-projectory-using-moveit?/) by [clark_txh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28091/clark_txh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-01-04**:
"but It isn't good for use." Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Clark,

MoveIt! does not support intermediate waypoints for joint space planning. The easiest way to do it is to plan separate paths: first to the middle waypoint, and then from there on to the final waypoint.If you both plan them before starting the execution, don't forget to set the start_state of the second segment so as to match the final state of the first segment.

You can then execute these trajectories in order, but if you want to turn them into one path, you can. To do this, you should merge the waypoints of both trajectories and re-run the time parameterization on the new trajectory.

With moveit_commander, this can be done with the [retime_trajectory](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html#a184c9cbfc5a8f82591843d29e6406dd9) function. In C++, it's a little more involved but certainly possible. Have a look [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/c07d8dd41802ba120afbad7821d21615fd09171d/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/wrap_python_move_group.cpp#L438) to see how it's done.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1